# Why doesn't the semaphore block the second thread? (C)

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads, semaphore

I want to write a simple C program to understand the semaphores better. There are two threads and they both call the same function. The first one, increases the global variable and the second thread, decreases the global variable.

I am trying to block the function from usage by the second thread before the first thread finished its work. But I am still getting the wrong answer: -2000. Looks like both of the threads have the offset -1. How can I fix that so the output will always be 0? I thought the sem_wait inside the function should block the second thread until the first one is over. Hence the offset should have stayed 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define NUM_LOOPS 1000
long long counter = 0;
sem_t sem;
sem_t sem1;
void* counting_thread(void* arg) {
    sem_wait(&sem);
    int offset = *(int*) arg;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_LOOPS; i++){
        //sem_wait(&sem);
        counter += offset;
        printf("offset = %d\n", offset1);


        //sem_post(&sem);
    }
    sem_post(&sem);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 1);

    pthread_t th1;
    int offset = 1;
    pthread_create(&th1, NULL, &counting_thread, &offset);
    //sem_post(&sem1);

    pthread_t th2;
    offset = -1;
    pthread_create(&th2, NULL, &counting_thread, &offset);

    pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    pthread_join(th2, NULL);

    printf("Finnal counter value: %lld\n", counter);
    sem_destroy(&sem);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pthread_create` takes a pointer to a variable as a parameter to pass in to the thread. You're pointing to the same variable, `offset` for both threads which means depending on the timing of you reassigning it they may get the same value passed in. Try making a separate variable for the second thread instead of reassigning the one already passed to the first one.

Comment: Yes, since threads use the same address space that is the problem. But there should be a solution using only semaphores.

Comment: Your reassignment of `offset` happens outside the semaphore lock (and outside the started threads), so it's a race condition no matter how much you lock inside the thread.

Comment: Even when I put a semaphore around the function call and variable update of the second thread(so that the offset will not be updated), I get a wrong result.

Comment: What most likely happens with your result (with reservations for race conditions being rather indeterminate) is; 1) You assign 1 to offset. 2) You tell thread 1 to start sometime in the future 3) You assign -1 to offset 4) You tell thread 2 to start sometime in the future 5) The threads both start, and both get the current value of offset, -1 as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [pthread_create man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create)

> Notes See pthread_self(3) for further information on the thread ID
>   returned in *thread by pthread_create(). Unless real-time scheduling
>   policies are being employed, **after a call to pthread_create(), it is**
>   **indeterminate which thread-the caller or the new thread-will next
>   execute.**

It is not guaranteed that who will execute next.
Maybe for you `main` thread is executing next and setting `offset to -1` before even new thread,  making it to read updated value from `offset` which is `-1`.

---

You can use conditional variable to synchronize.

**For example :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define NUM_LOOPS 1000
long long counter = 0;
sem_t sem;
sem_t sem1;
pthread_cond_t cond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; 
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; 


void* counting_thread(void* arg) {
    sem_wait(&sem);
    int offset = *(int*) arg;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond1); 

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_LOOPS; i++){
      counter += offset;
        printf("offset = %d\n", offset);

  }
    sem_post(&sem);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 1); 

    int offset = 1;
    pthread_t th1;
    pthread_create(&th1, NULL, &counting_thread, &offset);


    pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &lock);
    pthread_t th2;
    offset = -1;
    pthread_create(&th2, NULL, &counting_thread, &offset);

    pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    pthread_join(th2, NULL);

    printf("Finnal counter value: %lld\n", counter);
    sem_destroy(&sem);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I always get the result as -2000 so I think the OS happens to run the second thread right after the first one is started. The offset value never even happens to be 1.

Comment: I always get the result as -2000 so I think the OS happens to run the second thread right after the first one is started. The offset value never even happens to be 1.

Comment: @lalalal Try using conditional variable as I have showed in example

Comment: This is the right answer, but I am still wondering why doesnt putting a sem_wait around the second thread call won't work. So basically what is the difference between this conditional case and sem_Wait. Because as far as I understand, the conditional statement waits for the first thread to conclude. Isnt it the same thing with sem_wait

Comment: @lalalal No, with there is possibility that with `sem_wait` the `main` thread will acquire the `semaphore` and goes ahead updating `offset to -1` then `new-thread` will acquire the `semaphore`. But with `conditional` variable `main` thread will wait on that mutex until the `new thread` signals it.

Comment: The pthread_cond_signal() could happen before the pthread_cond_wait(), in which case the wait would wait forever.   Also, the mutex isn't optional; you need to have the mutex held before calling wait().